# How do you specify percentages of verbs/actions?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I've been googling around a bit for an answer and I can't seem to find anyone else asking this question. Apologies in advance if I'm wrong.

In English, you can say 'I do around 70% of the cooking'. How would you say that in Japanese?
Are non-する verbs like 'I do 30% of the carrying of boxes' different?

Comment: [This post may be interesting](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33582/when-talking-about-percents-can-i-use-%e3%83%91%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bb%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88-as-well-as-%e5%89%b2%e5%88%86) although it's **5割 written in Japanese** . Some may prefer to use kanji numbers (五割) in these use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it depends on the nature of actions or just contexts, but structures like *ActionのX%/X割はSubjがVerb* or *ActionはX%/X割SubjがVerb* can be broadly used.

Another thing is that it sounds more natural when actions are more concrete tasks/objects, instead of just cooking or carrying.

Some examples (with possibly non-idiomatic translations)

- 家事の7割は私がやっている *I do 70% of the household chores*
- 食事の準備は７割がた私がやっている　*As for preparation of meals, about 70% of the time I do it.*
- (引っ越しの時)荷物の８割は彼が運んだ *(When moving a house) he carried 80% of cardboard boxes*

Comment: If you want idiomatic translations, they're "I am done 70% of the chores" "I do 70% of the meal preparation" "He carried 80% of the carboard boxes (when we were moving)"

Comment: Also, do you have a stray た in sentence 2?

Comment: @Riolku Thx. And re:た, no. ７割がた means *about 70%*. I edit the translation.

Comment: I suppose, in the spirit of the original question, can we extend this to percentages that are not multiples of 10? I know わり is 10%, but can we be more specific?

Comment: @Riolku I can't really imagine a situation (in En or in Jp) where people say this kind of thing and are that specific.  In some cases, numbers like 七割五分（75％） are possible, but not really other non-5 numbers.

Comment: Hm. True, this grammar is pretty rare as it is. I think we can leave it at this then, thanks!